# Cant authorize unverified application

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I added credentials.json in my project. I wrote some code which must make new event in my calendar. When I run my code I also check my Google Calendar but I see there no new event which must be made by my code. Also I don't see token.json in bin/debug folder. How can I solve that issue?
P.S I use the same account

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts;
using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Rendering;


namespace Kyrsovoi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void GoogleAPI()
        {

            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
               
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
               
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {

                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }

            var ev = new Event();
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
            start.DateTime = new DateTime(2020, 10, 17, 11, 0, 0);

            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
            end.DateTime = new DateTime(2020, 10, 17, 11, 30, 0);


            ev.Start = start;
            ev.End = end;
            ev.Summary = "MyEvent";
            ev.Description = "TestScription";

            var calendarId = "primary";
            Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarId).Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Event created: %s\n", ev.HtmlLink);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 newForm = new Form2();
            newForm.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form3 newForm1 = new Form3();
            newForm1.Show();

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have OAuth2.0 identificator of my project. But in "access OAuth" window I can see only "verification not required"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an app that you are testing it hasn't been verified yet. You will see the following screen.

[image]

## press advanced

If you press the **Advanced** button you will see the following

[image]

## authorize the app.

This will let you authorize an unverified application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, finally I can finish my project

Comment: Also how can I pass authorization if I don't have "your connection isn't private" I'm using callendar for descktop app not site? I tried to do it with my hands in google.console, but it requiers url on main window of program, but I don't have it

Comment: Not sure i understand what you mean.  If you have a desktop app then you should be using native (other) credentials which doesn't require a redirect uri.  You will still need to verify your application even though its a desktop application.

Comment: I mean what I should do if I don't have any domain required in OAuth registration window? Because I want to make desktop app which will add events in my google calendar on "https://calendar.google.com/" and show them in my app? Like I don't have any site domain to use it in "main app's window domain" e.t.c

Comment: Where do you need a domain exactly?  You need a place to put up your privacy info, that you will have to host someplace.   Thats technically a GDPR requirement and not a Google requirement.   And its probably not related to this question.